# Remove "end" in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

When I write

```
\If{condition}
    {
        \textbf{return true}\;
    }
```

The output is like below[image]

However, I don't want **end** line. If possible, I want like this:

**if** *condition* **then** **return true;**

Is it possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is entirely covered in the [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) (section **10.4 if-then-else macros**), and is provided by `\lIf` (short for `l`ine `If`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\newcommand{\True}{\textbf{true}}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
  initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
    \lIf{condition}{\Return{} \True}
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I use `lIf`, the semicolon is automatically inserted at the end of **true** and there is a space between the word and the semicolon, unlike your snapshot.

Comment: @cagirici: Why is that? Please provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your problem.

Comment: it was because my mistake. That worked for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: why line number does not show up? How could I show the line number?

Comment: @Avatar: The package option `linesnumbered` adds line numbers to each algorithm.

Answer (score 41):

For that you should add `noend` option when declaring the package:

```
\usepackage[noend]{algorithm2e}
```

Comment: Why is this answer not higher?

Answer (score 4):

Use `\uIf{condition}` instead:

```
\uIf{condition}
    {
        \textbf{return true}\;
    }
```

From the official `alorithm2e` [documentation](https://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) (Section: if-then-else macros):

`\uIf{condition}{then block without end}`

Gives the following output:

[image: if then without end]